# include QWidget

Tags: moveit, cmake, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a package (where I use mainly MoveIt! functionalities) where in a .cpp file I am including the headers listed below, which themselves include QWidget. I read a bit about what QWidget and Qt are, and it has little to do with what I want to do. I tried to add:

```
set( headers
    include/moveit/motion_planning_rviz_plugin/motion_planning_display.h
    include/moveit/motion_planning_rviz_plugin/motion_planning_frame.h
 )

qt4_wrap_cpp(MOC_SOURCES ${headers})
```

Since those two are the headers which include Qt stuff. I still have the same problem:

```
fatal error: QWidget: No such file or directory
#include <QWidget>
```

I installed ros-indigo-qt-* but it didn't help. I found a QWidget and a QObject under /usr/include/qt4/, so I guess I should find a way to link those to my package. Am I right? And what should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257528/include-qwidget/) by [HenrySleek](https://answers.ros.org/users/29535/henrysleek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) on 2017-03-21**:
Those header files that you are including (In your CMakeLists.txt file I assume)  contain Qt Panel implementations that are used by rviz but they grab the moveit capabilities from other lower level moveit libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A colleague of mine was seeing the same issue, but only with Qt5 (ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04). You have a `qt4_wrap_cpp` command in there, though -- are you using Qt4 or Qt5?

I'll assume you need Qt5; he had to resolve a number of issues, and I don't recall which one exactly applied to the `No such file or directory` error. Making sure the following  lines are in your `CMakeLists.txt` file will cover almost all the issues he had (note that I'm leaving out some parts, such as te `catkin_package(...)` section):

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  qt_build
  ...
)
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(QT_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets)
qt5_add_resources(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
qt5_wrap_cpp(COMMON_MOC_FILES <your_files>)
...
add_executable(<your_exe> ...)
target_link_libraries(<your_exe> ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

As I recall, it was the `include_directories` line above that solved the issue you're having. Also, don't forget to update your `package.xml` file, including:

```
<build_depend>qt_build<build_depend>
<run_depend>qt_build<run_depend>
```

To reiterate, the above assumes Qt5 (kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04); Qt4 requires a different `CMakeLists.txt` setup.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2017-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HenrySleek](https://answers.ros.org/users/29535/henrysleek/) on 2017-03-22**:
I finally found my answer here: http://answers.ros.org/question/135916/how-can-i-use-qt-5-with-ros-catkin/
Which is an extension of your answer. Thank you very much.